# How do I get the color depth and/or the resolution from a byte string in Python?

Tags: python, image, data-structures, mp3, byte

^ As above. Is this possible?

I'm using a library to get image data from an mp3 and it returns the data as a byte string but to display the image I need to get the resolution and color depth.

Ideally I would prefer a library written in Python without dependencies so as to make my app as portable as possible.

If it's not too much trouble I would appreciate an example with the answer, thanks.

Comment: What library are you using? Does it not document the format it returns the image data in?

Comment: "it returns the data as a byte string"

Comment: Skimming the googles, it looks like image data will normally be either JPG or PNG, so zeekay's suggestion of using PIL is probably the best way to go. Is there a content-type field associated with the image  data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to work with images in Python. In your case you can do:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> from PIL import Image

>>> im = Image.open(StringIO(image_string))

>>> im.size, im.bits
<<< ((1654, 1279), 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the image has headers (which you could read with something like exiftool), or the image does not have headers, in which case you can get the size and color depth from the specification, either of the container tag for mp3, or from the standard for the graphic.

Most bitmaps nowadays are 24bit color.